# How to Break an Else If Condition

Tags: java, if-statement, break

I want to break out of an else if condition where it has an inner if condition, if the inner if condition inside becomes true like below, please suggest me a way.

```
 if(condition1=true){

        }
    else if(condition2=true){

           if(condition3=true){

              do activity 1;
              //I want to break here if condition3 is true, without executing activity 2 & 3
            }

          do activity 2;
          do activity 3;

    }
```

Comment: I hope that `=` is for the sake of the example and not instead of `==` (Which shouldn't even exist).

Comment: @MarounMaroun just only `if(conditionN)`

Comment: Put an else block after "condition3=true" with do activity2 and 3 in it

Comment: Umm... what about an `else` for `if(condition3)?`

Comment: Read about the `if` statement:http://www.dotnetperls.com/if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
else if(condition2){
       if(condition3){
              do activity 1;
              //I want to break here if condition3 is true, without executing activity 2 & 3
        }
        else
        {
              do activity 2;
              do activity 3;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In java you can use `break` only in loop `for` or `while` or `switch/case` or named blocks

But you if you have method `void` you can write `return;`

Something like:

```
void foo(){

if(condition1=true){

        }
    else if(condition2=true){

           if(condition3=true){

              do activity 1;

              return;
            }

          do activity 2;
          do activity 3;

    }
}
```

Comment: True, tough `return` will end the execution of the method. It would be a valid option if there's no logic after the if.

Comment: "In java you can use break only in loop for or while or switch/case." Wrong. You can also `break` out of named blocks.

Comment: @MaximShoustin Random example I found: https://gist.github.com/andy-morris/1441082

Comment: nice, i never used block names. good to know, added to answer

Answer (score 1):

Others already answered with restructuring the blocks. If checking of conditions don't need to happen in sequence, you can do-

```
if(condition3=true){
    do activity 1;
} else if(condition2=true){
    do activity 2;
    do activity 3;
} else if(condition1=true){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could go for an `else` statement.

```
...
if(condition3=true){
    do activity 1;
} else {
    do activity 2;
    do activity 3;
}
...
```

Or, if you prefer, you can extract that entire block of code to a separate function and have it return right after activity 1.

I think you could also use a named block:

```
...
doActivities:{
    if(condition3=true){
        do activity 1;
        break doActivities;
    } else {
        do activity 2;
        do activity 3;
    }
}
...
```

However, that's dangerously close to an outright goto and is probably not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

No need for break. This should do it.

```
if(condition1=true){

} else if(condition2=true){
    if(condition3=true){
        do activity 1;
        //I want to break here if condition3 is true, without executing activity 2 & 3
    } else {
        do activity 2;
        do activity 3;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact, I would try the way that is easier to read:

```
if(condition1)
{

}
else if(condition2 && condition3) {
      do activity 1;

}
else if(condition2 && !condition3) {
      do activity 2;
      do activity 3;
}
```

This way you avoid nested ifs and keep your code very easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

If-else patterns like this strongly hint at having some class structure to handle the cases.

```
Activity activity = ActivityFactory.getActivity(conditionCause);
activity.execute();
```